# What is the best way to keep the User's Lockout status in ApplicationUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to save the user's lockout status in my ApplicationUser (inherited from IdentityUser) in Asp.Net Mvc (Core or NetFramework), so which implementation is better from the design perspective?

### 1. User with IsActive property and LockoutReason enum property, separately

```
class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public bool IsAcitve {get;  set;}
    public UserLockoutReason LockoutReason {get; set; }
}

enum UserLockoutReason 
{
    NotLocked,
    LockedByAdmin,
    MaximumWrongPasswordAttemptsReached,
    ...
}
```

### 2. User with ActiveStatus enum

```
class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public UserActiveStatus ActiveStatus {get; set; }
}

enum UserActiveStatus
{
    Active,
    LockedByAdmin,
    MaximumWrongPasswordAttemptsReached,        
    ...
}
```

p.s: This design is going to be as an UserManagement's part to our IdentityProvider, so it's is so important to us to implement the best way we can

Answer (score 1):

I would go in this direction:

```
class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public UserActiveStatus ActiveStatus {get; set; }
}

enum UserActiveStatus
{
    Active,
    LockedByAdmin,
    MaximumWrongPasswordAttemptsReached,        
    ...
}
```

Since the `ActiveStatus` is the final information that you will need for the user, there will be need to branch of `user.IsActive` in if-else statements, and then getting the `LockoutReason` in case it's locked account won't be neccesary

Comment: OK, but how can I keep Unlocking status of the Users, updated?

Comment: I (AspNet Identity) locked out the User (John Doe) after 3 times wrong password attempts. After 3hours when he/she comes back and login again, he/she is valid to login and I will update his ActiveStatus to 'Active'. But when he won't come back to the system in next 10 hours, How can I update his ActiveStatus to 'Active' after 3 hours?